# What do we know about schizophrenia and mathematics?

Tags: mathematical-ability, schizophrenia

Schizophrenia is usually associated with intellectual problems. I don't think that cognitive deficits are only associated with vulnerability to schizophrenia, though there is the [much cited](http://apt.rcpsych.org/content/6/3/161)

> Russell et al (1997) recently proposed that intellectual decline in
>   schizophrenia was a nothing more than a ‘myth’. They followed up
>   patients who had received an intelligence test as a child, who then
>   developed schizophrenia, and had their intelligence re-tested some 19
>   years later. There were no differences between the child and adult
>   IQs. However, others have criticised this study on the grounds that
>   the sample was unrepresentative in that the individuals had presented
>   to child psychiatry units and were far more intellectually impaired
>   than subjects in other studies of children who subsequently developed
>   schizophrenia.

From my research prior to this question, it seems that there is a loss of ability, but likely not chronic decline over the course of the illness, one before or during the transition to psychosis. Another well known [meta review](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/schizophreniabulletin/24/3/10.1093/oxfordjournals.schbul.a033337/2/24-3-425.pdf?Expires=1498115081&Signature=WE8cEp5ighHFm31AEDe1Yj29b~rOWrLjU6BJgFR2TOGdaEVI7nzTSf9OPNxcLxRalbJLr1nGar7KnjD2zstbfH0k53h~4y3bssMxMg17SPDMZK4GZ5N-4vQ6Gq9C8HgjWdtaJtwiSwjfq37qSk89Z~qAeoxu7SyilTVJ7QszrAlznKvJaCispITxyTTnXViI-9knLd0tvhlqsbwHWtiM80UysO7m2lVgLlBNUynzYy6yJ0fQQrAi0F9eGgB1CYuMGgrFSCQGOzZerZr3QkMTf8FHnpGdayK9Qz5JQGbzJu~0Ghp8BhmLu9Sf6seiKMXJAEeeSQ~9UNOa9C5lanBY5w__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q) claims this, that there's

> no support for hypothesizing a degenerative
>   process in schizophrenia once positive symptoms appear... a static encephalopathy rather than a degenerative process

I've seen it said that it is centered on mathematical ability.

What do we know about mathematical ability pre and post psychosis, in schizophrenia? e.g., was John Nash a worse mathematician after he went mad?

### References

Russell, A. J., et al. (1997) *Schizophrenia and the myth of intellectual decline*. American Journal of Psychiatry, 154(5), pp 635–639.
DOI: [10.1176/ajp.154.5.635](https://doi.org/10.1176/ajp.154.5.635) PMID: [9137118](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9137118) WOS: [A1997WX13000009](http://apt.rcpsych.org/lookup/external-ref?access_num=A1997WX13000009&link_type=ISI)

Answer (score 1):

> I spent times of the order of five to eight months in hospitals in New
>   Jersey, always on an involuntary basis and always attempting a legal
>   argument for release. And it did happen that when I had been long
>   enough hospitalized that I would finally renounce my delusional
>   hypotheses and revert to thinking of myself as a human of more
>   conventional circumstances and return to mathematical research. In
>   these interludes of, as it were, enforced rationality, I did succeed
>   in doing ***some respectable*** mathematical research.

Seems like he himself is saying his research suffered while unwell and not staying in institutions.

However, the [standard](http://ajp.psychiatryonline.org/doi/pdf/10.1176/appi.ajp.2008.07081242) deficit in IQ, of it seems around 10 points, may be inconsequential in someone like Nash. Even if the executive function and memory impairments are more significant.

Comment: Where is this quote from?